# How to load CDN JS files in a Windows Store App?

Tags: javascript, winjs, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to load remote javascript files in a Windows Store App (written in JavaScript)?

Answer (score 1):

Well, that depends:

If your app is aimed for deployment on a web context, the answer is yes, otherwise (on a local context), script references are restricted for the locally packaged scope.

**Source**

- *[Features and restrictions by context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465373.aspx)*, on MSDN's Windows Store apps Dev Center.

Comment: quote: A Windows Store app using JavaScript contains at least one HTML page. That page, and any other pages you include in the app itself, generally run in the app's local context. When you use an iframe to navigate to a remote page, that page runs in the web context and has limited access to your system.

-- This means I can put an iframe in my page and load my javascript file?

Comment: I was coding it as you answered, will post again when I'm done!